# Unusual Viewport Issue

Tags: 3d-view, navigation

So, I'm not sure what's going on here. But I just finished an animation in another file and came to this model I'm working on and... well I don't know how to explain it but any time I get close to the object or camera, it begins to disappear. I'd rather not factory reset as I have a lot of custom things set up. Any idea's what causes this? I use Shift+f to move around, scroll to zoom in and out etc... Blender 2.79b (still need to get used to 2.8 I have used blender a lot but still a noob) [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause is almost definitely your clip distance. You can make the objects you are looking at bigger or change the clip distance by pressing N in the viewport and changing 'Clip Start' to a smaller value.[image]

Comment: No, that's what I thought at first too but I'm not in the camera. I'm just floating around.

Comment: It affects the viewport as well, not just the camera.

Comment: I changed it though and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Oh, wow. I was changing it in the camera settings and not the properties panel. I'm an idiot. Thank you so much MWolfe